# net reflector and visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, decompiling, reflector

I've lost the source code for one of my programs.  Is there anyway to disassemble all the code in .Net reflector and then load it into Visual Studio (express preferably), and hopefully get the designer view as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about the Forms designer you might want to check out this link from the red-gate groups ([problem with datasets when use reflactor to retrieve project](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewtopic.php?t=9410&highlight=designer)).  At the very bottom, I put a link to a hacked version of Jason Bock's File Generator which splits form files into 2 partial class files.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this plugin](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) for .Net Reflector.

Comment: It already does this without a plug-in.  Right-click assembly and choose Export.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the .NET Reflector built in dissasembler...

Comment: I know but I'd like to get the designer, or at least be able to edit the code and recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik's [JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx) tool does this beautifully.  Find the assembly and click the "create project" button, and within minutes you have a compilable Visual Studio project.